# Delete specific parts in a txt file

Tags: python, split, txt

I am working on a txt file which and in between the data that I need there are also information that I want to delete. For instance the txt file is built like this:

```
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep|
-------------------------------
---------------
----------------
info|I|dont|need|
----------------
---------------
------------------------------
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep
|I|want|to|keep|this|info|
-------------------------------
---------------
----------------
info|I|dont|need|
----------------
---------------
------------------------------
```

how can I delete everything between the dashes?

When I read the file I would like to have just something like this:

```
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep|
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep
|I|want|to|keep|this|info|
```

update: is it possible to just delete everything in between the dashes? the format of the info between them can be different so I would like to find a one fits all solution

Comment: It looks like all the lines you want to keep begin with a `|` character and all the ones you want to remove don't. Is that right? If so, you can loop over the lines and just output to a new file all the ones beginning with `|` by checking with the `startswith` string function.

Answer (score 0):

Type `str` comes with a feature `startswith` to check if the string starts with a specific user-defined character.

More information can be found in the following [documentation - python startswith](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm)

```
with open("<file_name>.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("|"):
            print(line)
```

Result:

```
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep|
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep
|I|want|to|keep|this|info|
```

Comment: What about the line `info|I|dont|need|` ?

Comment: [@anea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18939903/anea) does the above answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Read each line to list and apply comprehnsion accordingly as follows. Add keywords you want to keep inside List `B` and play with it.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]


B = ['important','want']

mask = [word for word in lines if any(want in word for want in B)]
mask = [w.replace('-', '') for w in mask]
mask ='\n'.join(mask)
print(mask)
```

output #

```
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep|
|important|data|that|I|need|to|keep
|I|want|to|keep|this|info|
```